# snakemake tutorial stuck in basics-step-5 (variant calling)

Tags: variant-calling, snakemake

I am learning to use snakemake. I am following the tutorial (https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/tutorial.html). In the section called "Basics", steps 1  to 4 worked well, processing one sample at a time, from mapping reads until indexing alignments.

```
snakemake --cores 2 sorted_reads/{A,B,C}.bam.bai
```

However, when I add the rule for joint variant calling (step 5):

```
snakemake --cores 2
```

I get the following error:

```
"WorkflowError:
Target rules may not contain wildcards. Please specify concrete files or a rule without wildcards at the command line, or have a rule without wildcards at the very top of your workflow (e.g. the typical "rule all" which just collects all results you want to generate in the end)."
```

It looks like I need to do this "rule all" step, any idea how to set this up?

This is how the snakemake file looks like:

```
SAMPLES = ["A", "B", "C"]

rule bwa_map:
    input:
        "data/genome.fa",
        "data/samples/{sample}.fastq"
    output:
        "mapped_reads/{sample}.bam"
    shell:
        "bwa mem {input} | samtools view -Sb - > {output}"

rule samtools_sort:
    input:
        "mapped_reads/{sample}.bam"
    output:
        "sorted_reads/{sample}.bam"
    shell:
        "samtools sort -T sorted_reads/{wildcards.sample} "
        "-O bam {input} > {output}"

rule samtools_index:
    input:
        "sorted_reads/{sample}.bam"
    output:
        "sorted_reads/{sample}.bam.bai"
    shell:
        "samtools index {input}"

rule bcftools_call:
    input:
        fa="data/genome.fa",
        bam=expand("sorted_reads/{sample}.bam", sample=SAMPLES),
        bai=expand("sorted_reads/{sample}.bam.bai", sample=SAMPLES)
    output:
        "calls/all.vcf"
    shell:
        "bcftools mpileup -f {input.fa} {input.bam} | "
        "bcftools call -mv - > {output}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Read [the snakemake documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#targets-and-aggregation). `all` is a pseudo-rule that accepts a set of one or more final output files as input and does nothing with them.

Comment: One clarification: Snakemake defaults to trying the first rule in the file (whether called the idiomatic `all` or anything else) and since in your case that has a sample wildcard, it doesn't know what to fill in for that wildcard.  (A typical `all` rule might use something like `input: expand("mapped_reads/{sample}.bam", sample=SAMPLES)` for example.)

Comment: Even more to the point: move `bcftools_call` to the top of the file and it will behave as your `all` rule.